# Defending "U" suffix after Hex literals

Tags: c, microcontroller

There is some debate between my colleague and I about the `U` suffix after hexadecimally represented literals. Note, this is not a question about the meaning of this suffix or about what it does. I have found several of those topics here, but I have not found an answer to my question.

**Some background information:**

We're trying to come to a set of rules that we both agree on, to use that as our style from that point on. We have a copy of the *2004 Misra C* rules and decided to use that as a starting point. We're not interested in being fully Misra C compliant; we're cherry picking the rules that we think will most increase efficiency and robustness.

Rule 10.6 from the aforementioned guidelines states:

> A “U” suffix shall be applied to all constants of unsigned type.

I personally think this is a good rule. It takes little effort, looks better than explicit casts and more explicitly shows the intention of a constant. To me it makes sense to use it for **all** unsigned contants, not just numerics, since enforcing a rule doesn't happen by allowing exceptions, especially for a commonly used representation of constants.

My colleague, however, feels that the hexadecimal representation doesn't need the suffix. Mostly because we almost exclusively use it to set micro-controller registers, and signedness doesn't matter when setting registers to hex constants.

**My Question**

My question is not one about who is right or wrong. It is about finding out whether there are cases where the absence or presence of the suffix changes the outcome of an operation. Are there any such cases, or is it a matter of consistency?

Edit: for clarification; Specifically about setting micro-controller registers by assigning hexadecimal values to them. Would there be a case where the suffix could make a difference there? I feel like it wouldn't. As an example, the Freescale Processor Expert generates all register assignments as unsigned.

Comment: `0x1234` has type `int`. `0x1234u` has type `unsigned int`. If this doesn't answer your question you need more help than we can give you.

Comment: MISRA was created with a specific (and somehow special) use case in mind. It is tightly connected to the automotive industry, where a lot of different CPUs of all sizes are used. It serves both the purpose of creating portable software across a wide variety of targets and tool chains and it strifes to dumb down C to a more "safe" language, befitting an industrial production of software. For finding out which of the rules of Misra are valuable to you and which would be detrimental, you should compare this use case with yours.

Comment: @zwol; I am aware of the type difference between the suffix' presence and absence. However, that does not satisfy my curiosity. I wish to know whether there are cases in which the absence may break a line of code, where the presence of it would prevent the code from breaking.

Comment: Maybe I should not leave an alternative unmentioned. Instead of using C, you could change to another language (if your own field of application allows). Instead of doing Misra C I would look into languages like Rust first. You get a ton more out of that language change than what you can ever get out of finding the perfect C coding styleguide.

Comment: @Deduplicator `0x1234` is representable in `int` even if `int` is only 16 bits wide, so it's still `int`.  I picked that constant on purpose to meet that criterion.

Comment: @JoeyvanHummel There are such cases, yes. They all follow directly from the type difference. If you cannot work them out for yourself, you need, like, an entire C textbook's worth of help - hence _more than we can give you_.

Comment: @zwol: I think I'll step out for now...

Comment: Ok, I think I see some confusion. English is not my primary language and I am trying to ask my question as clearly as I can. Please bare with me. I understand the impact of signedness on the functionality of a program. My question is specifically about setting microcontroller registers by assigning hexadecimal values to them. Would there be a case where the suffix could make a difference there? I feel like it wouldn't, yet (for example) the Freescale Processor Expert generates all register assignments as unsigneds.

Comment: I think the "U" topic is tightly coupled to the "UL, ULL" discussion. There is also a MISRA rule for that. Once you target more than 1 platform you will find yourself in a conundrum ;)

Comment: Be explicit. Coding is about "write what you mean", not "write what the rules say". If you mean `unsigned`, write the `U`; if not, leave it.
The argument regarding "just used for setting registers anyway" isn't a good one, because that's the purpose of every variable and constant, eventually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Appending a `U` suffix to all hexadecimal constants makes them unsigned as you already mentioned.  This may have undesirable side-effects when these constants are used in operations along with signed values, especially comparisons.

Here is a pathological example:

```
#define MY_INT_MAX  0x7FFFFFFFU   // blindly applying the rule

if (-1 < MY_INT_MAX) {
    printf("OK\n");
} else {
    printf("OOPS!\n");
}
```

The C rules for signed/unsigned conversions are precisely specified, but somewhat counter-intuitive so the above code will indeed print `OOPS`.

The MISRA-C rule is precise as it states *A “U” suffix shall be applied to all constants of unsigned type.*  The word **unsigned** has far reaching consequences and indeed most constants should not really be considered unsigned.

Furthermore, the C Standard makes a subtile difference between decimal and hexadecimal constants:

- A hexadecimal constant is considered unsigned if its value can be represented by the unsigned integer type and not the signed integer type of the same size for types `int` and larger.

This means that on 32-bit 2's complement systems, `2147483648` is a `long` or a `long long` whereas `0x80000000` is an `unsigned int`. Appending a `U` suffix may make this more explicit in this case but the real precaution to avoid potential problems is to mandate the compiler to reject signed/unsigned comparisons altogether: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` or `clang -Weverything -Werror` are life savers.

Here is how bad it can get:

```
if (-1 < 0x8000) {
    printf("OK\n");
} else {
    printf("OOPS!\n");
}
```

The above code should print `OK` on 32-bit systems and `OOPS` on 16-bit systems. To make things even worse, it is still quite common to see embedded projects use obsolete compilers which do not even implement the Standard semantics for this issue.

For your specific question, the defined values for micro-processor registers used specifically to set them via assignment (assuming these registers are memory-mapped), need not have the `U` suffix at all. The register lvalue should have an unsigned type and the hex value will be signed or unsigned depending on its value, but the operation will proceed the same. The opcode for setting a signed number or an unsigned number is the same on your target architecture and on any architectures I have ever seen.

Comment: Great example, demonstrating why C cannot be "saved" with a style guide!

Comment: Nice answer and MSVC does give warning *negative integral constant converted to unsigned type*.

Comment: While there are opposite opinions - my habit was to compile all my C code with a C++ compiler. Benefits: More type checks and knowing it will interop with C++ code in nearly all cases (the unfortunate #include <stdbool.h> being one of the exceptions)

Comment: @BitTickler second that "unfortunate `stdbool.h`". I never understood why it was introduced, and still manage perfectly well without it.

Answer (score 3):

With all *integer-constants*

Appending `u/U` insures the *integer-constant* will be some *unsigned* type.

---

Without a `u/U`

1. For a *decimal-constant*, the *integer-constant* will be some *signed* type.
2. For a *hexadecimal/octal-constant*, the *integer-constant* will be *signed*  or *unsigned* type, depending of value and integer type ranges.

---

Note: All *integer-constants* have positive values.

```
//      +-------- unary operator
//      |+-+----- integer-constant
int x = -123;
```

---

> absence or presence of the suffix changes the outcome of an operation?

When is this important?

With various expressions, the sign-ness and width of the math needs to be controlled and  preferable not surprising.

```
// Examples: assume 32-bit `unsigned`, `long`, 64-bit `long long`

// Bad       signed int overflow (UB)
unsigned a = 4000 * 1000 * 1000;  
// OK
unsigned b = 4000u * 1000 * 1000;  

// undefined behavior
unsigned c = 1 << 31
// OK
unsigned d = 1u << 31

printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof(0xFFFFFFFF));  // 8  type is `long long`
printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof(0xFFFFFFFFu)); // 4  type is `unsigned`

//              2 ** 63
long long e = -9223372036854775808;     // C99: bad "9223372036854775808" not representable
long long f = -9223372036854775807 - 1; // ok 
long long g = -9223372036854775808u;    // implementation defined behavior **

some_unsigned_type h_max = -1;  OK, max value for the target type.
some_unsigned_type i_max = -1u; OK, but not max value for wide unsigned types

// when negating a negative `int`
unsigned j = 0  - INT_MIN;  // typically int overflow or UB
unsigned k = 0u - INT_MIN;  // Never UB
```

** or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Comment: Interesting example with: `some_unsigned_type i_max = -1u;`. I guess the takeaway is that MISRA-style coding guidelines should not be followed blindly....

Comment: @DavidBowling Many rules have exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific question, which was loading register(s), then the U makes it an unsigned value, but whether the compiler treats the n-bit word pattern as a signed or unsigned value it will move the same bit pattern, assuming there isn't any size extension that would propagate an MSB. The difference that might matter is if the register load operation will set any processor condition flags based on a signed or unsigned loading. As an overall guide if the processor supports storing a constant to configuration register or a memory address then loading a peripheral register is unlikely to set the processor's NEG condition flag. Loading a general purpose register connected to an ALU, one that can be the target of an arithmetic operation like add increment or decrement, *might* set a negative flag on loading so that e.g. a trailing "branch (if) negative" opcode would execute the branch. You would want to check the processor's references to be sure. Small instruction set processors tend to have only a load register instruction, while larger instruction sets are more likely to have a load unsigned variant of the load instruction that doesn't set the NEG bit in the processor's flags, but again, check the processor's references. if you don't have access to the processor's errata (the boo-boo list) and need a specific flag state. All of this only tends to come up when an optimizing compiler re-aranges code with an inline assembly instruction and other uncommon situations. Examine the generate assembly code, turn off some or all compiler optimizations for the module when needed, etc.